# text entered in edittext with multiple new lines pressed when displayed in textview doesnt display whole text

Tags: android, android-layout

i have an edit text inactivity one where i input text , the text could be a single sentence or multiple sentences entered by hitting enter, which takes to new line.
I am passing the text entered in edit text of activity one to activity two through intents and collecting the string value and displaying the edittext string value by setting it to text view.

What i see is it only displays single line and lines below line one are not getting displayed.

Suggestion please

the code is as follows

```
description=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.description);
send_description=description.getText().toString();



t_desc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.descp);



<TextView              

android:id="@+id/descp"  
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/id5"
android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
android:gravity="left"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:maxLines="10" />
```

Comment: Code for reading the text and sending it to another activity please.

Comment: Also, print your text in logcat in both activities, if all the lines are there, follow the  answers already provided.

Answer (score 0):

Set properties of TextView like this

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="10"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:text="@string/message"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

In your activity class use this code

```
TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Comment: what problem you are facing in this or any error is there because its is working my side..

Comment: can you please paste your code of second activity to set data and logcat

Comment: sorry its actually problem with retriving from server , storing it in a string and then setting the string value as settext for text view, i am getting only one line from server though i am sending all line to server

Comment: ohk..so now you get solution to your problem...so appie coding.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the text you're putting in the TextView is short, it will not automatically expand to multiple lines. If you want the TextView to always have n number of lines regardless of the length of the text in it, set the `android:lines`

```
android:lines="n"// you can set n=2 and see the result
```

And, If you define your TextView's LayoutWidth to something like 120 dip then it will be multiline

Comment: but if the length of single word is longer than 120dip then some of the letters of the word dont get display and if the word if followed by another word it gets displayed in the next line.

Comment: like if the words are asdfghjklkhhd asdghgh asdfg then the asdfghk takes 120dip rest of the letters in word dont get displayed and the next words asdghg and asdfg get displayed in next lines, i have this roblem when i fix the width of textview